# How to open the PDF files in Powerbuilder windows application

Tags: pdf, powerbuilder, datawindow

I saved the datawindow in PDF format using SAVEAS method and I want to open the saved file in Acrobat reader. But in web application after save as method using Downloadfile() i'm able to open it. I think using OLEobject it is possile but i don't know how to do that. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to view the document (ie, no interaction with your PowerBuilder application) you can use the 'RUN' command.
Example:
RUN('C:\temp\mydoc.pdf')

This will open the file using whichever program is associated with .pdf files within your Windows settings.

Answer (score 0):

We simply use the Internet context service to open the PDF URL:

```
inet l_inet
string ls_url

// set ls_url to the URL to open

GetContextService("Internet", l_inet)
l_inet.HyperlinkToURL(ls_url)
```